# How many temporary/staging tables to use during the transform step of ETL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, etl, data-cleaning

My first thought is to first load data from S3 to a temporary table, apply the necessary transformations and then INSERT INTO target, final table. All the tables would have the same columns and are in Redshift.

However, how big of a performance hit would there be because of using multiple UPDATEs? Would it be better to split UPDATEs and filtering between multiple temporary tables for daily batch processing.

Instead of S3 -> TEMP -> FINAL, the flow would look like S3 -> TEMP1 -> ... -> TEMPN - > FINAL, where "->" would be "INSERT INTO".

Also, is it better to create temporary tables (CREATE TEMP TABLE) on the spot and dropping them every day, or use persisting temporary tables that would be truncated every day. I think using persisting temp tables would be the better choice as it allows me to check how the data looked as it was loaded and transformed that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are seeing there are lots of ways to run an update process and which is better will depend on factors that are not presented here.  First off let's clarify what a TEMP table is and differentiate it from a staging table.  A temp table only lives as long as the current session (connection) is active.  If the connection drops then so does the TEMP table.  A staging table is a permanent table used for staging data which more closely matches what you are describing you parts of your question.  I'll use these two terms to be clear about which is being made (TEMP or staging).

Your question revolves around how big of a performance hit it would be to have a series of tables in the ETL (ELT?) process to improve, I expect, diagnosability / debug-ability.  This is a fine goal but there are some downsides as with all tradeoffs in the real world.
If this is correct these tables will need to be staging tables as TEMP tables will disappear when the ETL session ends.

Saving a bunch of staging tables when one could be used has some downsides but how big these are depends on you situation.  If your cluster is fairly idle and the ETL data payload isn't huge then the impact to the ETL process of the extra tables will be real but not large (a couple of seconds or less).  These impacts are mostly around setting up (or truncating) the staging or TEMP tables.  But if your cluster is running other workloads when ETL runs then the impact can be much larger.

You see there are many "resources" in a Redshift cluster that all need to be shared by everything running on the database.  Some like memory allocation can be (somewhat) controlled through the WLM.  Others cannot.  The two biggies are network bandwidth and disk bandwidth.  There is a fixed capacity to these bandwidths in Redshift and even though they are high, they are finite.  There are other limits to Redshift's ability to execute a total workload but these in my experience are the big two.

Every time you create a table, TEMP or permanent, the data is stored to disk.  This means a write to disk as well as distributing the data per the distribution settings of the table.  Then when the table is accessed the data needs to be read from disk.  All this unneeded data movement will have some impact, how large will depend on how big it is and what else is going on at the time.  So you see the impact will be moderately small up to very large depending on a lot of factors, not the least of which is how many tables are you creating.  The cost of doing this will need to be offset by the benefit of having these extra tables which is a business decision.

A common pattern is to load (COPY) data to a temp or staging table and then extract the DELETE patterns to one staging table and the INSERT data to another.  Once the deletes and inserts are applied to then save these tables with a date stamp in the name and possibly unloaded to S3.  After a while these sets of data are deleted, 1 month is common.  This way you can figure out 'what happened' if things go sideways.  This plus good database backups can be used to recover from code bugs.

Your secondary question is about whether it is better to drop and recreate or truncate.  There have been a number of performance improvements to both of these statements. With a grain of salt, I'll offer my slightly dated experience comparing these.  Both are fast but I saw drop and recreate as slightly faster (fewer dependencies to manage).  That said the main difference is in how they interoperate with other aspects of the database.  DROP will fail if there are dependent views (unless cascaded) and table permissions will be lost.  DROP cannot be run in a transaction block and since it needs an exclusive lock on the table can be held off my another session reading the table.  TRUNCATE can run in a transaction block but will force a commit so transaction changes will become visible to all.  It is usually these differences that made the decision about TRUNCATE vs. DROP and there are other options such as DELETE and ALTER TABLE APPEND that have their own set of plusses and minuses.

So I'd generally advise against creating more tables than are actually needed in the ETL process when all needs are weighed (including performance and business needs).  You may have excess capacity now but usually Redshift clusters get busier over time.  The guiding principal here is don't move large amounts of data more times than is necessary.